# Is PHP's require_once() what I need if I want my site to load if AND ONLY IF the menu loads correctly?

Tags: php, require-once

I'm kind of confused.

I would put all the HTML for the menu in a .php file and have the engine require it right?

Comment: please define *loads correctly*.

Comment: Maybe I didn't express it correctly. I want a way to tell PHP "please load my menu up there, but don't even bother showing anything if I wrote the location of the menu.php file wrong."

Comment: then require is not what you want require will abort, include will display a warning.

but you could: if(file_exists('path/to/your/file.php')){ require_once('path/to/your/file.php'); } 

but i would wonder why should the file not exist ? can it have diffrent names ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the manual](http://it.php.net/require), the require() function will produce a fatal error if it cannot find the required file. So, if you require() the menu and the menu file is not present, you page will not show.
But if the menu file is found and contains errors, the page will show them.

Answer (score 1):

`require_once()`, and more specifically `require()` in general, will throw a fatal error (which will cause the page to stop loading) if the file does not exist. If there is an error in the file itself, `require()` will not change what happens. `require_once()` (and `include_once()`) are used in the case that you might have two or more files that need the same file to work. Basically, the `_once` functions will not let the same file be included multiple times (which is good, because you cannot redeclare functions and such).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using require() to load blocks of HTML, just use:

```
print file_get_contents('html/menu.html');
```

Comment: Why use a complex function and a language construct to replace a perfectly acceptable language construct?

Comment: Because if you readfile() you don't have to parse what you have required, it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what do you call "loads correctly", but yes, you can put all the HTML for the menu in a .php file and have the engine require it

Answer (score 0):

These are the four basic possibilities:

- **require**_... stops the script if there's an error
- **include**_... continues execution if there's an error
- ..._**once** only loads the file the first time you use it
- ..._*nothing* loads the file every time you use it

Of course, in normal circumstances, there should never be errors ;-)